# Multiple attachments to a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, file-upload

I have a form where I have to add multiple attachments. This functionality should be dynamic like user can select as many files as he want and cancel any of them.

On the frontend, I created a file input element and upon its "onchange", am adding another file input element with different id and same name. The name am using is "attachment[]" as I need to send the attachments as an array.

Submit button invokes a javascript function where am using jquery to get the parameters and create a formdata. The function snippet is

```
function send()
{
var form = document.getElementById("composeForm");

var formElements = form.elements;
var formdata;
for (x in formElements)
{
  //each element that has type='file' and value is 0 is what we want to delete later
  if(formElements[x].type=='file'&&formElements[x].value.length!=0)
  { 
        console.log(document.getElementById(formElements[x].id).files[0]);
    formdata = new FormData();
    var file = document.getElementById(formElements[x].id).files[0];
    formdata.append("attachment[]", file);
  }
}

if (!formdata)
{
    formdata = new FormData();
}

formdata.append("subject", document.getElementById("subjectInput").value);
if (formdata) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../ws/attach.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (res) {
            alert(res);
        }
    });
}

return false;
}
```

But the problem is that its always sending the last added file in the parameters. The above included console.log in showing all the files i.e

```
File {webkitRelativePath: "", lastModifiedDate: Thu Dec 06 2012 03:01:55 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), name: "backup.txt", type: "text/plain", size: 10584}
File {webkitRelativePath: "", lastModifiedDate: Wed Dec 19 2012 16:24:36 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), name: "acknowledgement.pdf", type: "application/pdf", size: 163435}
```

But the chrome inspect element shows that the only parameter being sent was

```
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryVYMwpCkBb8zK6tg0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachment[]"; filename="acknowledgement.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

Is there anything am missing?

Comment: You should use `var x`. No need to make `x` global!

Answer (score 0):

Well it is a silly mistake that I made. The error was due to initializing FormData every time :(

```
formdata = new FormData();
```

Thanks anyways to them who spent time on it.